# Does an object in H2xE hyperbolic space remain convex when projected into the Beltrami–Klein model?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

If I had some arbitrary convex 3D object that that lives in H2xE hyperbolic space and project the two hyperbolic dimensions into a Beltrami–Klein cylinder space, would the projection also be convex?

For context in why I am asking: I want to simulate physical collisions in H2xE. My thought is to project the hyperbolic dimensions to Beltrami–Klein (which as I understand retains linearity), then perform the collision tests on the resulting shapes as if they were fully Euclidean. But this could only feasibly work if I had a guarantee that convex objects remain convex when projected.

Comment: If your projection and its inverse send geodesics to geodesics, then yes.

Comment: You have to define your spaces : is $E$ the 1D real (Euclidean) axis (It is not a standard notation) ? You use $H_2$ as realized as the Beltrami-Klein representation but you can as well take the upper half-space with hyperbolic structure, or the Poincaré disk... Moreover, please, learn the basics of Latex `$H_2 \times E$` for $H_2 \times E$ instead of `H2xE`

Answer (score 1):

No. The curve

$$x(t)=\tanh(at)\cos(\theta)$$
$$y(t)=\tanh(at)\sin(\theta)$$
$$z(t)=bt$$

represents a geodesic in $\mathbb H^2\times\mathbb E^1$, but not a straight line in $\mathbb E^3$ (unless $ab=0$).